# Kick someone to somewhere

Tags: complements

Is it correct to say like that meaning to send someone there?

> Kick someone ***to hell***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It literally means to send someone there using physical violence. However, the phrase is frequently used figuratively to mean to dismiss someone through vigorous action without necessarily meaning physical violence.

Comment: and is "Kick someone out to hell" correct too?

Comment: That does not strike me as idiomatic in American English. "Kick X out" means to remove, literally with violence and figuratively with firmness. It does not fit with specifying a destination.